# Split list in tuples of three

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4...]
```

which have `n*3` elements. I want to be able to do something like

```
for a, b, c in three_tuple_split(L)
```

in a pythonic way but can't come up with one.

Comment: This has to be a dupe ...

Comment: And it is!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: @mgilson Not this is not, here, the aim is to split the list into 3 (or n) equally sized parts, not of size n, but of size len(l)//n.

Comment: @Schoolboy -- I don't think so.  If that was the case, OP would say that they wanted `a,b,c = three_tuple_split(L)` without the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inefficient but pythonic solution:

```
for a, b, c in zip(*[iter(seq)]*3): pass
```

For a more efficient implementation, look at the `itertools` [grouper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

for a, b, c in grouper(3, seq):
    pass
```

Comment: I thought I was looking for something shorter, but I must have been mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: @JonasByström That's the efficient version. The short version is simply `for a, b, c in zip(*[iter(seq)]*3): pass`

Comment: @JonasByström There is a shorter version. [Look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788596/1931274)...

Comment: @Schoolboy that isn't shorter!!

Comment: @jamylak: That's beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
mylist = range(21)
def three_tuple_split(l):
    if len(l)%3 != 0:
        raise Exception('bad len')
    for i in xrange(0,len(l),3):
        yield l[i:i+3]
for a,b,c in three_tuple_split(mylist):
    print a,b,c
```

Comment: This returns a list containing lists of size 3. Not 3 lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just use slices and a for loop.

```
def break_into_chunks(l,n):
    x = len(l)
    step = x//n
    return [l[i:i+step] for i in range(0,x,step)]
```

Or a slower one:

```
def break_into_chunks(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+len(l)//n] for i in range(0,len(l),len(l)//n)]
```

To use:

```
for a, b, c in break_into_chunks(L,3):
```